# Gulp has 2 tasks conflicting with each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I have both javascript and css files that I am using a forked repo of gulp-rev lib[1] that both renames the files and updates the file references within the html file.

Unfortunately, there is a race condition between the two tasks resulting in either the stylesheet reference to the md5-named file OR the js files winning out.

I have tried to use promises as well as callbacks (see below) to allow for syncing of the tasks, but never are both of the css and js md5 references made.

sindresorhus's lib only renames the files and does not fix the links, so is there a better way to fix the html links, or is using the forked plugin they way to go (with some fixes that I am missing)?

```
gulp.task('rev', ['rev-js'] );
gulp.task('rev-js', ['rev-css'], function(cb) {
  var context = rev.Context();
  gulp.src(['./build/public/js/woddy.js', './build/public/js/angular.js', './build/public/js/components.js'])
    .pipe(rev(context))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public/js'));
  gulp.src('./build/public/app.html')
    .pipe(context.replace(/src="js\/(\w+\.js)"/g, 'src="js/{{$1}}"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public'));
});
gulp.task('rev-css', function() {
  var context = rev.Context();
  gulp.src('./build/public/styles/woddy.css')
    .pipe(rev(context))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public/styles'));
  gulp.src('./build/public/app.html')
    .pipe(context.replace(/href="styles\/(\w+\.css)"/g, 'href="styles/{{$1}}"'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public'));
});
```

1. https://github.com/dtinth/gulp-rev

Comment: Also see the docs about running the tasks in series : https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/running-tasks-in-series.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty much all operations within gulp are asynchronous, which means you need to use one of the [3 supported methods for notifying when a task is complete](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#async-task-support).  (If a task is truly synchronous, you don't need to do anything.)

1. Return a stream from a method (usually the easiest)
2. Return a promise (rare in gulp)
3. Use the callback method supplied to the task function.

First, you've got the callback argument in your `rev-js` method.  By including the variable (`cb`), but never using it, that task will *never* "complete", so `rev` will hang around waiting for it.

Second, you've got two sets of streams in each task, which are being run simultaneously — not one-after-the-other as you might think.  For example, in `rev-js`, the js task is started, then the html task is started, then either may process and complete in any order.  Most likely, the HTML task will complete before all the JS files have been processed.

Personally, I'd split out the HTML task and use one of the existing plugins (such as [gulp-inject](https://npmjs.org/package/gulp-inject), which is easy), and then handle that separately.

So, for that case, your file would look like this

```
gulp.task('rev', ['rev-html'] );

gulp.task('rev-html', ['rev-js', 'rev-css'], function() {
  // change to reference specific JS and CSS files as necessary
  return gulp.src(['./build/public/**/*.*', '!./build/public/index.html'])
    .pipe(inject('index.html'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public'));
});

gulp.task('rev-js', function() { // NOTE: no `cb` here
  var context = rev.Context();
  return gulp.src(['./build/public/js/woddy.js', './build/public/js/angular.js', './build/public/js/components.js'])
    .pipe(rev(context))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public/js'));
});
gulp.task('rev-css', function() {
  var context = rev.Context();
  return gulp.src('./build/public/styles/woddy.css')
    .pipe(rev(context))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./build/public/styles'));
});
```

---

Now, if you really want to handle the injection manually, then you should use a [stream combiner](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/combining-streams-to-handle-errors.md) and return the result of that stream.  But you still need to have the JS step complete before the HTML step.

Comment: Thanks for the help (again :).  Not calling the callback was probably due to some undos (there were lots), but I was way off since I was just calling it after calling the async methods, which was then the reason things were still async.  I resorted to using timestamps since that was something that bypassed the async issues, but it also  results in people always having to download unchanged angular files.    One thing that is still unclear to me is weather the chained tasks (['rev-js' 'rev-css']) are run async to one another as well. Could you clarify this one?

Comment: Task dependencies are run simultaneously.  You should keep trying to make it work — the `rev` plugin works great for me.

Comment: I will definitely use what you suggested.  If you use the rev plugin how do you do it? The above example uses a fork of the rev plugin that supplies the context, so is there another way using sindresorhus's version?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by supplying the context.  I basically concat everything, run it through rev, and inject it.

Comment: I ended up rewriting most of the gulp tasks. I switched from the usemin plugin to inject and using the rev plugin was a lot easier.  Thanks for the help, it clarified a lot of things.

Comment: mind if you post your gulpfile with rev? looking for a way to pipe ngmin and rev in gulp-usemin.

Comment: I've got a [preliminary gulpfile here](https://gist.github.com/OverZealous/8551946), although I haven't updated the gist in a bit.  It does contain `rev` working with `ngmin` and `inject`.  Check the `compile-scripts` and `compile-html` tasks.